# How to terminate a loop into Python multithreads

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, flask

i'm trying to create a simple script with which i can take some screenshots using selenium Chrome and Flask.

```
import threading
import requests
from flask import Flask
from selenium import webdriver as wd


html = requests.get(website_to_scrape).text

def webpage(html_string):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.root('/')
    def dummy_page():
        return html_string
    app.run()

p = threading.Thread(target=webpage, args=(html, ), daemon=True)
p.start()
p.run()

browser = wd.Chrome()
browser.get('my_proxy_from_flask_')
browser.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

How could i change my code in order to interrupt the Flask.run() loop once i take the screenshot?

Or if there's a way that while the flask.run() loop is running i could change the html_page from another thread? Part of this code will be in a loop where different html_string argument will be passed.

I'm not using straight selenium chrome to take screenshots for personal reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the url to your flask proxy as query parameter, then make a request from flask and return the page to achieve what you want

```py
import threading
import requests
from flask import Flask, request
from selenium import webdriver as wd


def webpage():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def dummy_page():
        url = request.args.get('url')
        html = requests.get(url).text
        return html

    app.run()

p = threading.Thread(target=webpage, daemon=True)
p.start()

browser = wd.Chrome()
url = 'example_url_of_the_site'
browser.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000?url={url}')
browser.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

By the way you have a typo in code `@app.root('/')` -> `@app.route('/')`